# How to reuse the code without multiple inheritance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, cocos2d-iphone

I have `SAGridMenu` class which is implementing method `align`. I also have class `SARadioMenu` which is implementing touch related routines. Both are doing their job fine individually.

```
SAGridMenu: CCMenu
SARadioMenu: CCMenu
```

What I want now is to create class combining those two classes - `SARadioGridMenu`. There is no multiple inheritance in Objective C so I can't have a class inherited from both. What is the most efficient way to combine them?

**Update(clarifications):**

Both subclasses are using ivars, so category is not a best option.

Basically I have two pieces of code. 1. align and 2. touch related. The ultimate goal is to have 3 classes without redundancy - `SAGridMenu, SARadioMenu and SAGridRadioMenu`. As a temporary solution I've inherited `SAGridRadioMenu` from `SARadioMenu` and copied `align` code into it. Hope to find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Various options, since they both inherit from `CCMenu`:

- Put the method in `CCMenu`.
- Put the method in a category on `CCMenu`, i.e. implement something like '@interface CCMenu (align)`. This is probably what I'd do.
- Add an intermediate class that inherits from `CCMenu` and is the superclass to both of your classes, something like

  ```
  SAGridMenu : CCMenuPlusAlign : CCMenu
  SARadioMenu : CCMenuPlusAlign : CCMenu
  ```

Comment: First option isn't good enough since I don't want to modify cocos. Second options requires hacks, since I have ivars. Third option is interesting, but doesn't appear I can re-use the touch related code. `SAGridMenu - OK`. `SARadioMenu - OK`. `SAGridRadio`... need to copy touch related events.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific details of the methods, you may be able to implement the methods `align` and/or the touch related routines as class methods. The class methods can take a `CCMenu` or a protocol with the necessary ivars as a parameter. For example, `SARadioGridMenu` would inherit from `SARadioMenu` and would call `[SAGridMenu align:self]`. `SAGridMenu` would also call `[SAGridMenu align:self]` in order to call the align method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Composition** in Your third class **SAGridRadioMenu** Like:

```
@interface SAGridRadioMenu : CCMenu {
    SARadioMenu * _radioMenu;
    SAGridMenu * _gridMenu;
}

//You can also create properties here
```

In this way your both  **SARadioMenu,SAGridMenu** classes stay reusable and without copying the code (no redundancy),,third class is ready to use.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: I don't see how composition may help here.

Comment: Can you explain why composition is not applicable here...@#